# input using for each loop

Tags: c++, loops, input, foreach

I have declared an array of constant size, and try to take input using a for-each loop, but
it is not able to take input for the total element of the array.

```
int main(){
  int a[5];
  for(int x: a){
    cin>>x;
  }
}
```

Is it not allowed to use a for-each loop to take input of the elements of the array?

Comment: Your loop will create a copy of the existing (indeterminate) value of the array. And that will lead to *undefined behavior* (using indeterminate values in any way leads to UB). You need to loop using *references* to the elements: `for (int& x : a)`

Answer (score 3):

In C++, when iterating over an array using a range-based for loop, it's crucial to use references if you intend to modify the elements within the array.

***Let's delve into the details to understand why.***

Consider your initial code snippet:

```
int main(){
  int a[5];
  for(int x: a){  // x is a copy of the current element
    cin>>x;
  }
}
```

In this code, the variable x is a copy of each element in the array a. Therefore, any modifications made to x within the loop will not affect the original array.

To address this, we should use references in the range-based for loop:

```
int main(){
  int a[5];
  for(int& x: a){  // x is a reference of the current element
    cin>>x;
  }
}
```

By using **int& x** instead of **int x**, we create a reference to each element in the array. This means that any changes made to x directly affect the corresponding element in the array a.

***Note:***

*The reason for this distinction lies in the mechanics of the range-based for loop. When using int x, a copy of each element is made, and any modifications only affect the local copy (x), not the original array. On the other hand, int& x creates a reference to the actual elements in the array, allowing for direct modification*.

In summary, using references in the range-based for loop ensures that modifications made to the loop variable affect the original array elements, making it a crucial consideration when you need to fill or modify an array during iteration.

Comment: I asked ChatGPT the same question and received nearly identical answer, word by word, why could it be so?

Comment: Please dont use AIs to create answers. This is actually banned on StackOverflow: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)